# i want to save my pdf into my iphone, pdfs url are with me through parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, download, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have parsed my xml and i got some images and their corresponding urls of pdf from server.so whenever i click on image i have their corresponding **url of pdf**.I am giving an alertView **on click of images** and when user select the download button of alertView it should **download the pdf from url into my iphone device**

CODE:-

```
@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize scrollView,receivedData;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{   
    [receivedData appendData:data]; 
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [myIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [myIndicator startAnimating];

    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_landscape.png"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;
    [background release];   

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://litofinter.es.milfoil.arvixe.com/displayxml1.aspx"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:150.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    int x=20,y=50;

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45,320, 480)];   
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,5000);
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

    for (Litofinter *lito in appDelegate.bookArray) {
        if([appDelegate.currentButtonPressed isEqualToString:lito.cName])
        {
            NSLog(@"Count == %d ===",[lito.productsArray count]);
            for (Products *prod in lito.productsArray) {

                NSString * urlString = [prod.thumbnail stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

                NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                [myIndicator stopAnimating];
                [myIndicator removeFromSuperview];

                UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]retain];
                [imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 150, 200)];
                [imageButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [imageButton setTitle:prod.pdf forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTapBook:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [scrollView addSubview:imageButton];

                x = x + 150;

                if(x >300)
                {
                    y = y +250;
                    x = 20;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];


}

-(void)onTapBook:(id)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    appDelegate.currentBookPressed = [button currentTitle];

//  viewController2 = [[PdfShowViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PdfShowViewController" bundle:nil];
//  [self presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Ver Catalogo!" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:@"Ver on-line",@"Descargar",nil];
    [alert show];

     /*[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",appDelegate.currentBookPressed] */ 
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  
{  

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];  

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Ver on-line"])  
    { 
        // i will show the pdf online here

    }  
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Descargar"])  
    {           

        // what to write to download the pdf
    }  

} 

-(IBAction)onTapBack{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [scrollView release];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with NSURLConnection and then I would reuse same code above, because you have it already declared properly.

Save data to NSData and then with writeToFile save it to main bundle.

So here is some more explanation how I would do it.

There are several ways to do it.

Here is how to do it with NSData

```
NSData *myFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_url"]]; [myFile writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"yourfilename.pdf"] atomically:YES];
```

Also you can use ASIHTTPRequest library which has been discontinued by author, but still works like it should.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *myDownloadRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"yourfilename.pdf"]];
```

But maybe easiest way of all because as I can see you have displayed pdf already, so it's contents are in receivedData is just to call

```
[receivedData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"yourfilename.pdf"] atomically:YES];
```

So actually you can reuse code that you have already wrote in viewDidLoad, replace url if necessary and after connection is closed save file to disk.

```
 NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://litofinter.es.milfoil.arvixe.com/displayxml1.aspx"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:150.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain me in some more detail... i am not getting it.. :(